# Problem asking for a list of the all the sums of the sublists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a code that will give us a list of the sublist sums. For example if the inputed list was [[5, 4], [2, 1, 7], [1]], we'd a get this in return [9, 10, 1].
My teacher is asking use not to use the sum function considering we haven't learned it yet.
I currently have a code but there's a few things I'm not sure about and it keeps returning an empty list.

**This is what I have:**

```
def sumSublist(inital_list):
    i = 0
    initial_list = list()
    finalList = []
    while i < len(initial_list):
        sublist = list[i]
        for j in sublist:
            sublistsum = 0
            sublistsum += j
            finalList.append(sublistsum)
        i += 1
    return finalList


print(sumSublist([[5, 4], [2, 1, 7], [1]]))
```

and it prints: []
Any help or suggestions would greatly help thanks

Comment: @TroyD Second year uni, just started learning code, taking the intro to compsci course meant for people with 0 coding experience, which is me haha

Comment: When you write `sublist = list[i]`, what are you expecting this to do?

Comment: Also: did you notice that your parameter is called `inital_list`, rather than `initial_list`? Either way, when you do `initial_list = list()`, what are you hoping to accomplish this way?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I made some mistakes in my understanding of how to use lists but I read up on some stuff and with the help of other answers to this, I understand I was doing absolutely nothing with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with your solution:

- There's a typo in the input parameter, it should be named `initial_list`, not `inital_list`.
- You must access the input list like this: `initial_list[i]`, this is incorrect: `list[i]`.
- You're destroying the input list in this line: `initial_list = list()` (that's why the result is empty.)
- In each iteration of the inner loop, the sum is lost in this line: `sublistsum = 0`, that's why this part must go *before* the inner loop.
- The line `finalList.append(sublistsum)` must go *after* the inner loop, once all the elements in the sublist have been added.

This should fix the problems:

```
def sumSublist(initial_list):
    i = 0
    finalList = []
    while i < len(initial_list):
        sublist = initial_list[i]
        sublistsum = 0
        for j in sublist:
            sublistsum += j
        finalList.append(sublistsum)
        i += 1
    return finalList
```

However, the above solution could be simplified if we just used `for` consistently:

```
def sumSublist(initial_list):
    finalList = []
    for sublist in initial_list:
        sublistsum = 0
        for num in sublist:
            sublistsum += num
        finalList.append(sublistsum)
    return finalList
```

But in real life, we should use `sum` and list comprehensions, this is how we'd write an idiomatic solution in Python:

```
def sumSublist(initial_list):
    return [sum(sublist) for sublist in initial_list]
```

Anyway, it works as expected:

```
sumSublist([[5, 4], [2, 1, 7], [1]])
=> [9, 10, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helped. I agree with just using the sum function, I would if I was making the code outside of the class but it's what she asked so I had to. Your explanation helped a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Whether that list comp is expected depends on who's expecting. I'd rather expect `list(map(sum, initial_list))`.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider first defining the `sum` function that operates on a list of numbers, and then applying it to every list of the `initial_list` (in my example, it's `xss`):

```
def sum(xs):
  # traverse each element of xs
  # and return the sum

def sum_sublist(xss):
  # traverse each element of xss
  # which are lists, apply the `sum` function
  # defined above on each, and return the list of the sums
```

Answer (score -2):

you can easily do this if it's just a list with one layer of nested lists:

normal way:

```
lst = [[1,2],[1,2,3], [1]]

summed = [[sum(i)] for i in lst]
```

without using `sum()`

```
# this does the same thing but in reference to what you were talking about
def sumSubList(lst):
    summed = []
    for i in lst:
        summ = 0
        for x in i: summ += x
        summed.append([summ])
    return summed

print(sumSubList(lst))
```

Comment: From the question: `My teacher is asking use not to use the sum function`

Comment: @MarkMeyer fixed, i skim over simpler questions sometimes